# What can be used instead Attribute Sample Texture node in Geometry Nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I wanted to go through this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Doqs_4FHo6U&t=36s), but at the very beginning it turns out that I simply do not have an Attribute Sample Texture node.

I use Blender 3.0.

Maybe this node was replaced with some new one, or is there an alternative way to reproduce the effect of this node?

Comment: I understand exactly what you mean, and it's actually not easy to keep track of. But this overview here can at least help you understand how the nodes have changed over the versions and what replacements there are for a particular node: [Can't find the node! Which node is available in which Blender version?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/273542/145249)

Answer (score 2):

Since that tutorial was made, the  Geometry Nodes system has radically changed. It now uses '[Fields](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/geometry_nodes/fields.html)', which are evaluated and interpolated at every requested coordinate of a given space, rather like shader nodes.

Given a vector-space, a texture node is now **implicitly** sampled at the relevant points , when an evaluation is asked of it:

[image]

Here, the *Wave* Texture node is evaluated at the 'Positions' (Equivalent to 'Object' *Texture Coordinate*s in shader nodes) of the subdivided input Geometry, automatically interpolated between its vertices. (The *Position* input node is actually optional, here, it is the default.)

If you prefer learning from videos, I would suggest, at least to start with, you seek out the ones made after 'Fields' were introduced.

Comment: Hey @robinbetts what is a better way to learn GN if not from videos?  I would love to find a "Geonodes for Idiots" kind of resource if there is one that you can recommend.

Comment: Hi @glen_candle ! I have to confess I've learned a lot of mine by reverse-engineering. I've started off with a general knowledge of transformations, coordinate-spaces, and an assumption of what Blender means by a 'field'. (A set of scalar or vector values  calculated at every point in space, sometimes linearly interpolated between samples) 3D procedural shader textures help with imagining those. Then I read the manual. Then, a node doesn't do what I expect :). Then I make the simplest possible trees I can, to find out what it _does_ do.

Comment: ha that's basically what I do as well, but geonodes is making me feel very dumb lately because just as soon as I think I get it, I can't seem to get anything done without another tutorial nudging me along ;)

Comment: @glen_candle. I believe (hope)  GN still has a long way to go? So I wouldn't get too tangled up in the details, yet, unless it's for a problem you need to solve for yourself. Erindale, Entagma, good video sources, IMO. And of course.. Get stuck, and ask here.

Answer (score 0):

I've stumbled on the same thing. The pace of *Geometry Nodes* breaking changes since their inception has made a lot of training resources obsolete.

I've not found a clear and up to date introduction material, so after trial and errors, I think I've come up with the *correct modern* way of doing a simple displacement map like in the mentioned tutorial. Tested on Blender version 3.3 (current LTS) and 3.4.

Robin Betts' proposed answer is a good pointer to the *Fields* feature, but I wanted to provide an updated way of doing the same effect as in the tutorial, maybe it can be useful to others.

The simplest solution I came up with:
[image: Simple height displacement]

Explanation:

- Now that the **Attribute Sample Texture** node is gone, you have to use the **Noise Texture** node (a specialized texture sampling with embedded noise controls).

  - No need to create a new attribute like in the video (noise), just pass along the Factor (Fac) float value.
  - No need to assign a source vector, default texture coordinates are used
  - The *Scale* parameter directly controls the strength of the displacement
- Create a new Vector with only the Z component with the **Combine XYZ** node
- **Add** this vector to the **Position** node

  - The **Position** node means the geometry attribute that is named `position`
  - Which geometry's attribute is evaluated in context of the current geometry flow (i.e. the grid mesh)
- Use the **Set position** node to update the source geometry's (i.e. the grid mesh) position

I can't provide a full updated tutorial, but if you want the same kind of animation as he does, you probably want something like that:

[image: Animated noise]